# Applying jquery plugin to new item in angularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a widget which uses angular for render and a jquery bootstrap plugin to toggle a checkbox.

```
<div class="notification" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
    <textarea ng-model="notification.text">
    <div class="make-switch" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="notification.status">
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="addNotification()">Add</button>
```

On first render when page loads everything goes right, but when I add a new Notification the plugin is not applied. And it is logically.

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myAppModule.controller('NotificationController',function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.notifications = [
        {
            text:'text1.',
                status: true
        },
        {
            text:'Text2',
            status: false
        }
    ];

    $scope.addNotification = function(){
        var notification = {
            text: "",
            status: true
        }
        $scope.notifications.push(notification);
        $timeout(function(){
            $('.notification:last() .make-switch').bootstrapSwitch();
        })
    }
});
```

And so I use $timeout and jquery ":last()" selector to apply plugin to the last item.

Is it correct?? Everything is working, but it looks not good.

Comment: So Notification adds or not?

Comment: Have checked your code. 1. textarea closing tag is missing. 2 .Check errors in error console. if any.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great candidate for a directive. See a more detailed explanation for the angular directives [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
When you have to modify the DOM in some way you should do it in a directive. It is considered a bad practice for the controller to access and modify the DOM, it should be working with the scope.

So in your case you can create a simple directive

```
directive('notificationSwitch', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bootstrapSwitch();
    }
  };
});
```

and inside your view you use this directive like so

```
<div notification-switch data-on="success" data-off="danger">
```

That way every time a new item is added with this directive, it's linking function will be called that will apply the bootstrapSwitch